# httpd not reading the document root in conf/httpd.conf as expected

Tags: linux, centos, apache-httpd

I have a Laravel project on my CentOS7 server which sits on the folder "/var/www/html/myProject".

I have changed my document root in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf to "/var/www/html/myProject/public" both in "DocumentRoot" and in the directory configure so when i enter the IP in the browser it will automatically show the project.

When i try to do so and access my IP through the browser i am greeted with the messages:

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access /form on this server.
>   Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

After further examination i have found out that in my /var/log/httpd/error_log i get the following error after every access attempt:

```
[Thu May 10 19:39:33.683522 2018] [core:crit] [pid 1994] (13)Permission denied: [client 79.182.62.1:51091] AH00529: /var/www/html/myProject/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/var/www/html/myProject/' is executable
```

That was very odd to me since the path is supposed to be /var/www/html/myProject/public, but the "public" is missing.

I have restarted my apache several times, and changed the DocumentRoot path to a fictional path just to check if it updates and it is.

Could it maybe be something in the .htaccess file? although i didn't change the file, i left it as Laravel created it.

Comment: I do not think it is permissions...have you created a Unix user called MyProject?

Comment: No. the user owning the directory is apahce

Comment: To inspect recent SELinux errors in detail, see [here](https://access.redhat.com/articles/2191331). Alternatively, to check for bad SELinux labels inside the DocumentRoot, use e.g. `restorecon -n -Rv /var/www`. (To fix, remove the `-n`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could either because of the Permissions on the public file. For now just give full permissions and see what it does

```
chmod 0777 /var/www/html/myProject/public
```

or

```
chmod -R 0777 /var/www/html/myProject
```

If still the page is inaccessible check the SElinux status on your host machine.

Type `sestatus` and check the current mode. It should either be disabled or in permissive mode. If its in enforcing mode then `httpd` web page may not display the contents as expected.

To set SElinux to permissive mode type the following command:

```
setenforce 0
```

Comment: Your recommendation is very unsecure!

Comment: Well its just the permission changes for now considering the fact the creator hasnt mentioned anything about security concerns. If so then permissions can be tweaked. Not a big deal

Comment: @Zorrom Both recommendations are poor advice.

Comment: @Zorrom "for now" does not make for a good answer to a question. When you have enough "reputation" from other contributions, the site will let you post comments to request e.g. troubleshooting steps from the asker. https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment

Comment: it's unsecured but the selinux did the trick so i will mark it as useful. thanks!

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I came across a similar issue and I shared my solution towards it and if I am wrong, then I am wrong.

Comment: @shayk Glad I could help

Comment: @Zorrom Usually you tell selinux what is the DocumentRoot, better than disabling it. Havent got time now to explain it better.